# Inheritance relationship between the type of the actual object and the object reference

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

For example I create an object like this:

`BankAccount b = new SavingsAccount();`

Now lets say that I want to access a method `addInterest()` that is in the `SavingsAccount` class I would have to do: `((SavingsAccount)b).addInterest();`

The question I have is why do I have to cast `b` to SavingsAccount? Isn't the actual object reference of `b` already an instance of `SavingsAccount` class? How does the `BankAccount` affect the object itself? I'm really confused as to what class is truly getting instantiated and how `BankAccount` and `SavingsAccount` are both functioning to help make the object `b`.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Read up on the difference between declared types and run time types and how method invocations are resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `BankAccount` type variable, it could have a `SavingsAccount` or any other kind of `BankAccount` in it, and only `SavingsAccount` has the method `addInterest()`. If you didn't have to cast, then you could write some code like this:

```
BankAccount b = new BankAccount(); // let's pretend this is a SavingsAccount
b.addInterest();
```

That would not work. To prevent this, the compiler has to reject programs that call a method that isn't defined in the variable type.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: you define b as object of type BankAccount, not SavingsAccount. If method addInterest() is only defined in SavingsAccount then it is not possible to call it on BankAccount instance.

However your SavingsAccount extends (or implements) BankAccount so you can store reference to SavingsAccount in b which is of type BankAccount because SavingsAccount is also a BankAccount.